# Check file history in Linux/Ubuntu/Centos

Tags: linux, centos

Can i check the file history like git or SVN in linux os. The modifications by date in Linux/Ubuntu/Centos. Any software that helps me do this?

Comment: Do u want to check file history in git or in Linux/Ubuntu/Centos?? Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: I want to check the history of a .java file in Linux. Centos.

Answer (score 4):

`Git` and `Subversion` are software packages whose purpose in life is to keep track of content changes in the files of a project. The OSes usually do not care about files history; they don't provide such a feature.

`Windows` and `macOS` include backup tools that run automatically in background (if they are enabled) from time to time and can be used to access **some** (not all) past versions of the files. This functionality comes with the cost of disk space used to store the past versions of files.

Linux doesn't provide such a tool (but you can install one, if you need it.)

I guess you are out of luck. You cannot recover a previous version of the file but you can install a backup software to avoid reaching this situation in the future.

Answer (score 3):

By default you can't. The filesystem simply stores the current state of the file, not its history (as 1615903 pointed out in the comments, there *are* some versioned filesystems that keep track of this kind of history, but they are largely unsupported in Linux - which means you probably aren't dealing with one, if you are, the filesystem documentation can guide you through the recovery of your file). It's possible that some forensics tool can at least attempt to recover some file's history but I'm not sure of that (and they will probably fail if the older file's sectors have been written on).

For the future, you can prepare in advance for similar problems by setting up some incremental backup (it can be done pretty easily with [rsync](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Using-rsync-for-Backups)), but it's still limited to the specific timeframes you set your script to run into.

Comment: _"The filesystem simply stores the current state of the file, not its history."_ - versioning file systems do exist, but no mainstream linux filesystems support any.

Comment: I assumed from the question the OP isn't using anything of that sort. I guess it's still a good idea to update my answer adding a note about that, just in case I assumed wrongly, thank you.

Comment: Filesystem is xfs.

Comment: XFS does not support versioning, as far as I know